# How to enable keyboard layout switching popup on Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, keyboard-layout

I am using Kubuntu 20.04. I set keyboard layout change shortcut to `Win+Space`, but whenever I use the shortcut keyboard layout switching popup is not shown.

[image: keyboard layout switching popup example]

Comment: How did you set that shortcut?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson System Settings -> Keyboard -> Advanced -> Switching to another layout

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Global Shortcuts
2. Choose KDE Daemon in Application Launchers
3. set Switch to Next Keyboard Layout to `Win+Space`

Comment: Do you get a "popup" that way? I don't. OTOH I'm playing with 21.04, and they seem to not be identical.